# How to move window to different desktop via keyboard in Lion?

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager, desktop

In Snow Leopard, to move a window to a different space, I had to use the mouse to select the window and use the keyboard to select the target space (e.g., ctrl + 1,2,3).

In Lion, what *keyboard* (maybe in slight conjunction with mouse as before) shortcuts can I use to move a window to a different desktop?

Comment: I'm still waiting for a keyboard-only solution for this that doesn't require third party software. Did you ever find an answer?

My reply to the answer below helps some but still requires the mouse: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43493/how-to-move-window-to-different-desktop-via-keyboard-in-lion#comment448751_43530

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pressing the shortcuts for changing desktops while dragging a window should still work, but the shortcuts have to be enabled in System Preferences.

[image]

[SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) supports for example assigning ⌃⇧→ to moving a window to the next desktop.

Comment: Yeah, it works, but Ctl and -> keys are on the opposite side of the keyboard.  That means two hands are required.  Clicking the mouse (or track pad) with my third hand is inconvenient.  This can be done IFF you have a non-Apple keyboard.

Comment: In Sierra using these shortcuts to move windows to another desktop produces annoying glitches. E.g. window will appear in both desktops.

Comment: @Bruce: I'm using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and have CapsLock+a mapped to left mouse button. Now I can click and hold with a keyboard shortcut (Caps Lock and a) and use Ctrl+<arrow> to switch to next desktop (or Ctrl+<num> to switch to specific desktop) and thereby move the window to that desktop, using a(n apple) keyboard only. (I've furthermore mapped CapsLock+j,k,l,i to arrow keys (in Karabiner, too). Thereby I can do this without leaving the homerow! These shortcuts comes in handy in a lot of situations! :) )

Comment: Once you have these shortcuts setup you can click and HOLD in the title area of a window and press Ctrl+<#> or Ctrl+<left/right arrow> to bring your window along with you to another space.

Comment: If there were a shortcut key to focus on an application than perhaps it could be paired with 'control + desktop #' to move the application to another desktop without requiring a third party application.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a mouse-less solution, using [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai). You can assign a keyboard shortcuts to move the windows across desktops. In my case I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>.

[image: BTT config]

Answer (score 4):

You can also (without modifying system settings) click and hold the window, hold down the control button, and drag to the edge of the screen.

Comment: For me on sierra, this works even without holding `^`

Comment: Love this solution! I don't really care if I have to use the mouse or the keyboard, but I shouldn't have to use the mouse AND the keyboard. This works wonderfully. Thanks!