# Moving an application window to another desktop or screen using the keyboard?

Tags: macos

In Windows, when I press the `windows key + any arrow button` the current application window moves. For example: `windows key + left arrow key`: the application window moves to the left of the display.

I want to know if this feature is available in OSX. If yes, how do I use it? If it's not a native feature, is there is a **free** third party application that might enable this feature?

Comment: Related even though it's for Lion: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43493/how-to-move-window-to-different-desktop-via-keyboard-in-lion

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50330/how-to-arrange-two-windows-easily-to-left-and-right-side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com) supports assigning a shortcut for resizing a window to fill the left or right half of a screen and for moving a window to another screen:

[image]

As does [Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate/):

```
bind left:ctrl;alt;cmd move screenOriginX;screenOriginY screenSizeX/2;screenSizeY
bind right:ctrl;alt;cmd move screenOriginX+screenSizeX/2;screenOriginY screenSizeX;screenSizeY
alias monitor-macbook 1280x800
alias monitor-dell 1440x900
bind up:ctrl;alt;cmd move screenOriginX;screenOriginY screenSizeX;screenSizeY ${monitor-macbook}
bind down:ctrl;alt;cmd move screenOriginX;screenOriginY screenSizeX;screenSizeY ${monitor-dell}
```

[Amethyst](https://github.com/ianyh/Amethyst) also supports assigning a shortcut for moving a window to another space. `throw-screen-2` (control-option-shift-e) moves a window to the second screen and `throw-space-2` (control-option-shift-2) moves a window to the second space.

Answer (score 0):

Once again [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) made my day. You can assign a keyboard shortcuts to move the windows across desktops. In my case I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd>.

[image: BTT config]